# Wie ist die Deklination des Wortes "alle"?

Tags: word-usage

Wie ist die Deklination des Wortes *alle*?

1. Frage: Ist das richtig?

   ```
   Nominativ: alle  guten Kinder
   Akkusativ: alle  guten Kinder
   Dativ    : allen guten Kindern
   Genitiv  : aller guten Kinder
   ```
2. Frage: Gibt es das Wort *alle* in Singular Form?
   [Hier](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch/alle.html) gibt es in Singular form:

   Ist das richtig?

   ```
   Nominativ: aller  gute  Hund
   Akkusativ: allen  guten Hund
   Dativ    : allem  guten Hund
   Genitiv  : alles  guten Hundes
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Die richtige Deklination hast du schon selbst verlinkt („Plural“-Spalte):

   ```
   alle guten Kinder/Hunde (Nominativ)
   aller guten Kinder/Hunde (Genitiv)
   allen guten Kindern/Hunden (Dativ)
   alle guten Kinder/Hunde (Akkusativ)
   ```

   Die Deklination hängt nur vom Substantiv ab, worauf sich „alle“ bezieht. Alle anderen Adjektive (wie „gut“ in deinem Beispiel) müssen natürlich in Kasus (Fall), Genus (Geschlecht) und Numerus (Einzahl/Mehrzahl) ebenfalls mit dem Substantiv übereinstimmen.
2. Die „Singular“-Form von „alle“ gibt es mit den in deinem Link gelisteten Deklinationen, wird aber nicht so häufig benutzt. Z. B.:

   ```
   Aller Anfang ist schwer. (Nominativ maskulin)
   zu aller Zeit (Dativ feminin)
   Alles Gute! (Akkusativ neutrum)
   ```

   Das von dir gebrachte Beispiel funktioniert nicht; hier würde man „jeder“ benutzen. Ich denke, dass der Singular nur für nicht-zählbare Substantive (siehe obige Beispiele) funktioniert.

   ```
   jeder gute Hund (Nom.)
   jedes guten Hundes (Gen.)
   jedem guten Hund (Dat.)
   jeden guten Hund (Akk.)
   ```

**Edit:** Als Reaktion auf rogermues Antwort bzgl. „Aller Anfang ist schwer.“ Ich bin kein Linguist, aber wenn das ein Genitiv sein soll, müsste es doch „allen Anfangs” heißen, oder?. Für mich sieht das wie ein Nominativ wie in „Jeder Anfang ist schwer.“ mit der Ersetzung Jeder<->Aller aus. Eine Begründung, warum das als Verkürzung eines anderen Satzes gelesen werden muss, wenn es so wie es ist ein korrkter Satz ist, würde mich interessieren.

Comment: AHA so es gibt die Singular -Form. Grammatikweise es ist korrekt Aber am meistens wir nutzen alle mit Plural, obwohl es nicht falsch mit Singular zu nutzen ist? Richtig?

Comment: OHHH das muss stimmen! 'Ich denke, dass der Singular nur für nicht-zählbare Substantive (siehe obige Beispiele) funktioniert.' Könnten wir das sichern?

Comment: Ich habe für den ganzen Tag geguckt? Die grammatischen Bücher sind nicht klar über das.

Comment: Gibt es ein Plural Form für das Wort jeder ?

Answer (score 1):

Die Verwendung von all im Singular ist eingeschränkt, weil die Idee von alle eben die Gesamtheit aller bezeichneten Dinge/Personen ist.

Singular neutrum kommt häufiger vor:
Alles Gute zum Geburtstag.
Ich kaufe alles, was Sie an Bildern von Maler X haben.

Aller Anfang ist schwer.

Das ist kein Sg maskulin, sondern "Der Anfang aller Dinge ist schwer, umgestellt zu
"Aller (Dinge) Anfang ist schwer". Die Form aller ist hier also ein Gen Pl.

Aller Tag/alle Frau ( Nom Singular) kommt aus logischen Gründen nicht vor. Aber es gibt bestimmte Fügungen wie

Alle Welt weiß das.

Auch verkürztes all + Plural/Singular kommt vor. All meine Sorgen, all mein Hab und Gut, all mein Geld.

Ich sehe schon zum Funktionswort all/alle bringt man einen guten Grammatikparagraphen zusammen.