# Die Deklination vom Indefinit-Pronomen "all" (nur für Sachen)

Tags: grammar, pronoun, indefinite-pronoun

Ich benötige die Deklination vom Indefinit-Pronomen "*all*" (nur für Sachen), ich weiß nur, dass es keinen Plural  hat und im Nominativ und Akkusativ "*all*-**es**" ist, aber die richtige Form weiß ich im Dativ und Genitv  nicht. Kann jemand mir helfen? Ich danke einem in Voraus!

Nehmen wir Beispiele:

**1**: Ich habe *alles* verstanden

**2**: *Alles* ist mir klar

Im ersten Satz "*alles*" ist Akk.-Ergänzung

Im zweite Satz "*alles*" ist Nom.-Ergänzung

Ich habe an Beispiele im Dativ und im Genitiv gedacht aber ich weiß nicht, wie das Indefinit-Pronomen ist (ich bin Italiener und in Italienisch weiß ich das), z.B.:

**3**: Trotz ______ gehe ich nach Hause

**4**: Ich spreche von ______, was ich mag

Comment: Wieso hat es keinen Plural? Doch hat es. [Siehe hier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/all). Wobei ich nicht ganz verstehe, was du mit "nur für Sache" meinst. Aber wahrscheinlich irrelevant für die Frage. Letzlich ist es noch ein Duplikat: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20176/1224

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht! Ich sage z.B. "ich habe alles verstanden" oder "alles ist mir klar", in diesen Fälle "alles" ist nicht ein Indefinit-Artikel und ich denke, dass es keine Plural-Form gibt! Warum haben Sie mir jene Seite verlinkert?

Comment: Es wäre gut, wenn Du ein Beispiel angeben würdest.

Comment: Die Frage, die hier als Duplikat angegeben wird, ist nicht die gleiche Frage und die Antworten dort sind nicht hilfreich für den OP hier.

Comment: @Em1... ist meiner Ansicht nach nicht wirklich ein Dupe, da es hier ums Pronomen geht, da um den Artikel. Die Antort bei der anderen Frage geht nicht deutlich auf das Pronomen ein. Sollte wieder geöffnet werden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Dativ wäre *allem* bzw *allen* im Plural.

Genitiv *alles* oder *allen* bzw *aller* im Plural.

Comment: sage ich denn : "Trotz alles/allen gehe ich nach Hause" und " Ich spreche von allem, was ich mag" ??

Comment: Richtig wäre "Trotz allem gehe ich nach Hause", wobei hier allem synonym für alledem ist. Der Satz "Ich spreche von allem, was ich mag" ist richtig.

Comment: Ich bedanke mich bei Ihnen! :D

Comment: Sehr gerne. Bitte vergessen Sie nicht, Antworten, die Ihnen geholfen haben, zu akzeptieren. Nur so können User auf GLSE wissen, dass Ihre Frage beantwortet wurde.